# How to get values of dynamically created input fields (Json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

input fields are created via jquery depend on user input 
If user type Quantity : 5 then i m created 5 input fields

for example if user give Quantity = 3 then this is how the html created dynamically using Jquery

```
<tr id = "tr_1">
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_no1" id="cont_no1" /><td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_size1" id="cont_size1" /><td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_type1" id="cont_type1" /><td>
</tr>
<tr id = "tr_2">
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_no2" id="cont_no1" /><td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_size2" id="cont_size2" /><td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_type2" id="cont_type2" /><td>
</tr>
<tr id = "tr_3">
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_no3" id="cont_no3" /><td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_size3" id="cont_size3" /><td>
  <td><input type="text" name="cont_type3" id="cont_type3" /><td>
</tr>
```

now i need to store all this input fields values in json.

```
            var jsonObj=  jsonObj || [];   
            for(var i=1; i<cont_qty; i++)
            {
                item = {};
                item ["cont_no"] = $('#cont_no'+i).val();
                item ["cont_size"] = $('#cont_size'+i).val();
                item ["cont_type"] = $('#cont_type'+i).val();
                jsonObj.push(item);  
            }
```

i tried like this but its not working the please someone help me. ThankYou

for your refrence here is full code, var auto_tr value is aligned here(with enter) for your purpose .

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$( "#cont_qty" ).change(function() 
{    
    var itemCount = 0;
    $("#munna").empty();

    var cont_qty = this.value;
    for(var i=0 ; cont_qty>i; i++)
    {
    itemCount++;
    // dynamically create rows in the table
    var auto_tr = '<tr id="tr'+itemCount+'">
                        <td>
                            <input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no'+itemCount+'" name="cont_no'+itemCount+'" value="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             <select class="input-mini" name="cont_size'+itemCount+'" id="cont_size'+itemCount+'">
                                <option>20</option>
                                <option>40</option>
                                <option>45</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="input-mini" name="cont_type'+itemCount+'" id="cont_type'+itemCount+'">
                                <option>DV</option>
                                <option>HD</option>
                                <option>HC</option>
                                <option>OT</option>
                                <option>FR</option>
                                <option>HT</option>
                                <option>RF</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="input-medium" name="cont_tonnage'+itemCount+'" id="cont_tonnage'+itemCount+'">
                                <option>24000 Kgs</option>
                                <option>27000 Kgs</option>
                                <option>30480 Kgs</option>
                                <option>Super Heavy Duty</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input  class="input-medium" type="text"  id="cont_tare'+itemCount+'" name="cont_tare'+itemCount+'" value="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input-medium" name="cont_netweight'+itemCount+'" id="cont_netweight'+itemCount+'" type="text" value="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input  class="input-mini" name="yom'+itemCount+'" id="yom'+itemCount+'" type="text" value=""></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="input-medium" name="cont_condition'+itemCount+'" id="cont_condition'+itemCount+'">
                                <option>IICL</option>
                                <option>ASIS</option>
                                <option>CARGO WORTHY</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                </tr>';     

        $("#munna").append(auto_tr);
    }
});


        $("#getButtonValue").click(function () 
        {
            var jsonObj=  jsonObj || [];   
            for(var i=1; i<cont_qty.value; i++)
            {
                item = {};
                item ["cont_no"] = $('#cont_no'+i).val();
                item ["cont_size"] = $('#cont_size'+i).val();
                item ["cont_type"] = $('#cont_type'+i).val();
                jsonObj.push(item);  
            }
            alert(jsonObj[0].cont_no[1]);
        });
 });
```

Comment: Your html is invalid.

Comment: what's the last `id=name ="cont_size2"` of the input?

Comment: sorry edited... @phillip100

Comment: I assume that the `id="cont_no1"` in `tr_2` is also a typo (just to make sure you have unique id's)? You could show us the method used to create these input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did small loop mistake :)

```
         for(var i=1; i<=cont_qty.value; i++)
                {
                    alert(cont_qty.value);
                    item = {};
                    item ["cont_no"] = $('#cont_no'+i).val();
                    item ["cont_size"] = $('#cont_size'+i).val();
                    item ["cont_type"] = $('#cont_type'+i).val();
                    jsonObj.push(item);  
                }
```

in previous one `i<cont_qty.value` this one used now just changed as `i<=cont_qty.value`

so the loop ran 3 times when qty is 4. now just added <=

ThankYou for your answers friends

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call your function after you created the html via jquery.

```
createHtml(); // function to create the html
storeValuesToArray(); // Your function to store data to array
```

Also make sure you properly close your tags `<tr></tr>`. And put `<tr>` inside a `<table>` tag.

And make sure your `cont_qty` is set to a value

Answer (score 0):

After you created the html and added all the fields necessary, you can catch all elements by using a selector like:

```js
var jsonObj=  jsonObj || [];
$('[name^="cont_no"]').each(function(){
  var i = this.name.split('cont_no')[1];
  var item = {};
  item['cont_no'] = $(this).val();
  item['cont_size'] = $('[name="cont_size'+i+'"]').val();
  item['cont_type'] = $('[name="cont_type'+i+'"]').val();
  jsonObj.push(item);
});
```